# How do I write Flink TIMESTAMP_LTZ to Elasticsearch using ISO-8601?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I have an Elasticsearch SQL sink in a Flink (PyFlink) job, where the sink table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE mysink (
  foo TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
)
WITH (
   ... my elasticsearch connection details
)
```

In my Elasticsearch index, field `foo` has type [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).

When I have a streaming insert into that table, I get an error:

```
failed to parse date field [2023-01-02 00:00:00Z] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]
```

Flink appears to be writing the field as a SQL format, which Elasticsearch does not accept.

What is the way of having Flink either output to Elasticsearch using ISO-8601 or an epoch millisecond timestamp?

(I know I could change the accepted date time format in my Elasticsearch index, but I'd rather keep the formatting loginc inside Flink, not have to change my storage schema).